# How can I save RTCP time information in video output

Tags: gstreamer, rtp

Is it possible to extract the NTP timestamps from the RTCP SR to be synchronized later?

I am currently recording my video and audio feeds separately using the following launch strings:

```
matroskamux name=mux ! filesink location=/tmp/video.mkv  udpsrc port=26770 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,payload=(int)101,encoding-name=(string)VP8,ssrc=(uint)608893168" ! .recv_rtp_sink rtpsession name=session .recv_rtp_src ! rtpvp8depay ! queue ! mux.video_0 udpsrc address=127.0.0.1 port=24694 ! session.recv_rtcp_sink
```

and

```
matroskamux name=mux ! filesink location=/tmp/audio.mkv  udpsrc port=26540 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio,clock-rate=(int)48000,payload=(int)100,encoding-name=(string)OPUS,ssrc=(uint)632722900" ! .recv_rtp_sink rtpsession name=session .recv_rtp_src ! rtpopusdepay ! queue ! mux.audio_0 udpsrc address=127.0.0.1 port=23815 ! session.recv_rtcp_sink
```

I am recording them separately because the video or audio may start and stop multiple times throughout the session (for example, the user begins with just audio, then starts streaming video, then stops audio, etc etc etc). I figured that it would be easier to just start/stop separate pipelines when the user starts/stops a stream rather than trying to stop an audio-only pipeline and switch to an audio+video pipeline (and potentially have a gap in the audio between the stop and the start).

As a proof-of-concept, I used the created timestamp of the resulting mkv file (using `gst-discoverer-1.0` and looking at the datetime field) and it *mostly* worked but seemed to be just a *little* bit off. I'm wondering if there's a way I can use the RTCP SR packets to encode the "real" timestamp for the start of the stream. It would be great if I could encode it into the mkv somehow but even if I could just access it in code with a signal then I could store the information elsewhere. I looked through the signals on [rtpsession](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtpmanager/rtpsession.html?gi-language=c#signals) but nothing was jumping out at me as a possible solution.